# What is the vscode api to create like " SCM Working Tree" window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I like to create to window like 'SCM working tree' window which appears in git changes

I need help with vscode api because I could not find it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vscode.diff` command for this, providing two URIs to use for the diff as arguments:

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand(
    'vscode.diff', vscode.Uri.file('C:\\a.js'), vscode.Uri.file('C:\\b.js'));
```

[image]

Comment: I am creating extension to find duplicate codes, so I need another tab to show the duplicate codes.

Comment: I don't follow. So you're not trying to open a diff window? You might want to be a bit more specific with the description in your question.

Comment: sorry, English is not my first language . I want to open diff like window , so that in new window, I can highlight the duplicate codes